# Error : "The title prop of a Button must be a String." How to change the Color of a text in Button Tag React-Native

Tags: react-native

I want to change the color of the Text in a Button Tag in React-Native. but I get the Error "Invariant Violation: The  Title prop of a button must be a string". Also, suggest me some Good npm to create Button in React-Native. I tried the Below Code but it Doesn't work.

The color property only changes the Background Color of the Button. I need to Change the Color of the Text.

```
<View style = {styles.container}>
   <Text style = {styles.maintext}>Add all your Social Media Profile ID</Text>

   <Button title="Yes, Take me there" color="#841584" />
   //only changes the Background Color

   <Button> <Text style={{color: '#ff0000'}}> Not Now </Text>  </Button>
   //this line shows the Error

</View>
```

Please help me with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The color attribute behavior depends on the platform you're using/simulating the app (on iOS it changes the text color and on Android the background: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html)

I'd advice you to use a TouchableOpacity tag which encapsulates the Text:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={...}>
  <Text style={{color: '#ff0000'}}>Some text here</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```